Module not found error when dynamically importing locales in i18next
I'm integrating i18next in my Next app by following this tutorial https://i18nexus.com/tutorials/nextjs/react-i18next and all the steps seem to be working as expected until I added the i18n.ts file in the app directory:
import { createInstance } from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next/initReactI18next";
import resourcesToBackend from "i18next-resources-to-backend";
import { i18nConfig } from "@/config/i18Config";

export default async function initTranslations(
  locale: string,
  namespaces: string[],
  i18nInstance?: any,
  resources?: any
) {
  i18nInstance = i18nInstance || createInstance();

  i18nInstance.use(initReactI18next);

  if (!resources) {
    i18nInstance.use(
      resourcesToBackend((language: "en" | "ar", namespace: string) => {
        return import(`@/locales/${language}/${namespace}.json`);
      })
    );
  }

  await i18nInstance.init({
    lng: locale,
    resources,
    fallbackLng: i18nConfig.defaultLocale,
    supportedLngs: i18nConfig.locales,
    defaultNS: namespaces[0],
    fallbackNS: namespaces[0],
    ns: namespaces,
    preload: resources ? [] : i18nConfig.locales,
  });

  return {
    i18n: i18nInstance,
    resources: i18nInstance.services.resourceStore.data,
    t: i18nInstance.t,
  };
}

I'm getting a Module not found error in the return clause of resourcesToBackend function and I'm not sure how to fix this.
I have the locales file in my src/ directory and I have the paths configured in tsconfig.json as
"paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }

I also added the following config in next.config as suggested by GPT:
webpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.alias["@"] = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");
    return config;
  },

Nothing seems to fix the dynamic import error.

import { i18nConfig } from "@/config/i18Config"; needs to be import i18nConfig from "@/config/i18Config"; without the curly braces{ ... } because it's exported withmodule.exports which is similar to export default and needs to be called without the braces. you can see also in the tutorial you are following they are using it without braces in step 3 in the middleware.js

I'm exporting i18Config using ES6 exports as export const i18nConfig = {   locales: ["en", "ar"],   defaultLocale: "en", };  so I don't think that's the problem in my case @MHDAlaaAlhaj
